# compiling latex: pplr8t.log font is missing

Tags: compilation, latex

I want to compile latex in the normal way, however it appears this on the terminal,

```
kpathsea: Running mktexmf pplr8t
! I can't find file `pplr8t'.
<*> ...:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input pplr8t

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input pplr8t

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: pplr8t.log: No existe el fichero o el directorio
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 26):

Install the *palatino* latex package or to be more font complete, the *collection-fontsrecommended* package, as in:

```
$ sudo tlmgr install collection-fontsrecommended
```